# Migrating data from a CSV source: Where should the source go?

Tags: migrations

I'm trying to do a migration of an old (and full of nodes and comments) D7 site, to a Drupal 8 brand new one.

In order to import only the contents, I'm trying to do the migration from a csv file (with the stuff that I've exported using views).

My question is, how to set the source? Full path?
I'm using a test csv file and I put it at the root folder, at the same place where the index.php file is.

I tried this:

```
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'http://www.example.com/myfile.csv'
...
```

And this:

```
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: '/myfile.csv'
...
```

(with and without the slash)

I keep receiving this error when I try to run the migration script:

> ```
> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
> HTTP Result Code: 500
> Debugging information follows.
> Path: /batch?id=20&op=do_nojs&op=do
> StatusText: Internal Server Error
> ResponseText: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
> ```

What should I do?

Comment: put source as public://csv/test.csv and sites default make a folder named csv and place the file inside that

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Please add it as a reply so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add the file as :

```
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: 'public://csv/test.csv'
```

And under sites/default make a folder named as csv and place the file inside that. It will work.